# Pandas outer merge returning out of place values and extra Nans

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes: `fpm` and `real`. See the samples below:

```
          month   fpm          region_id
94934     11  3.106522e+07    5300108
94935     23  3.476453e+07    5300108
94936     35  4.480962e+07    5300108
94937     47  4.148533e+07    5300108
94938     59  4.324909e+07    5300108
94939     71  5.908792e+07    5300108
94940     83  6.218772e+07    5300108
94941     95  6.881312e+07    5300108

        region_id  month    gdp_region
72397    5300108     35  5.390220e+10
72398    5300108     47  5.845612e+10
72399    5300108     59  6.707650e+10
72400    5300108     71  7.573268e+10
72401    5300108     83  8.466141e+10
72402    5300108     95  9.340400e+10
```

I want to merge them by `region_id`and `month`.

In order to do so, I used the command:

```
j = pd.merge(real, fpm, how='outer', on=['region_id', 'month'], left_index='off', right_index='off')
```

What happens is that some alien values from `fpm` column joins the same row of `region_id 5300108` and the actual `gdp_region` is not actually joined at the correct `region_id` and `month`.

I have checked and both columns are of the same type: `int`

Here is the WRONG result. Notice that the INDEXES are different. I explicitl set `index='off'`.

```
   region_id  month    gdp_region           fpm
72397    5300108     35  5.390220e+10  1.649367e+07
72398    5300108     47  5.845612e+10  1.968157e+07
72399    5300108     59  6.707650e+10  2.088269e+07
72400    5300108     71  7.573268e+10  4.027545e+06
72401    5300108     83  8.466141e+10  1.197713e+06
72402    5300108     95  9.340400e+10  1.383501e+06
72403    5300108    107  1.102996e+11  1.718117e+06
72404    5300108    119  1.243238e+11  1.827867e+06
72405    5300108    131  1.441741e+11  2.053814e+06
72406    5300108    143  1.545690e+11  2.597804e+06
72407    5300108    155  1.641013e+11  2.908494e+06
72408    5300108    167  1.759067e+11  3.394452e+06
72409    5300108    179  1.974321e+11  4.022392e+06
94934    5300108     11           NaN  3.106522e+07
94935    5300108     23           NaN  3.476453e+07
94936    5300108     35           NaN  4.480962e+07
94937    5300108     47           NaN  4.148533e+07
94938    5300108     59           NaN  4.324909e+07
94939    5300108     71           NaN  5.908792e+07
94940    5300108     83           NaN  6.218772e+07
94941    5300108     95           NaN  6.881312e+07
```

Appreciate any suggestions. 
Thanks.

Comment: `pd.merge(real, fpm, how='left', on=['region_id', 'month'])`

Comment: If I use how='left' I lose the information for 'fpm' that I have for month 11, for example.

Comment: Then using `how='right'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet with reproducible input would be helpful. The same goes for your desired output. You could try this at first with `left_index = False` and not 'Off':

```
import pandas as pd

fpm = pd.DataFrame({'idx':[94934,94935,94936,94937,94938,94939,94940,   94941],
                   'month': [11,23,35,47,59,71,83,95],
                   'fpm':   [3.106522e+07,3.476453e+07,4.480962e+07,    4.148533e+07,   4.324909e+07,   5.908792e+07,6.218772e+07,6.881312e+07],
                   'region_id':[5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108]})
fpm = fpm.set_index(['idx'])

real = pd.DataFrame({'idx':[72397,72398,72399,72400,72401,72402],
                   'region_id':[5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108,5300108],
                   'month':[35,47,59,71,83,95],
                    'gdp_region':[5.390220e+10,5.845612e+10,6.707650e+10,7.573268e+10,8.466141e+10,9.340400e+10]})

real = real.set_index(['idx'])

j = pd.merge(real, fpm, how='outer', on=['region_id', 'month'], left_index=False, right_index=False).sort_values(['region_id', 'month'])
print(j)
```

Does this represent your desired output?

[image]

Comment: Funny, your implementation represents the desired output. But, that is not what happens with my actual data. I guess that means that the problem is not in the merge command, but somewhere in the data of the DataFrames?

Comment: Wow. Go figure. Now I did `d = real`, `e = fpm` and `f = pd.merge(d, e, how='outer', on=['region_id', 'month'])` and it worked! Thanks. Although I still did not understand why it had not worked in none of the good answers. It must be a problem on the generation of the DataFrame. Maybe.

Comment: Indeed the type of the variables on on have to match! That's the key.

Comment: Cool that you figured it out.

Comment: Yeah, @vestland But, the first time Python let me down. As I did successive merges, pandas kept bringing my `int` into `float`. Anyway, if you test `int(1) == float(1)` Python returns `True` as it should. Lessons to take away: Always use strings as Keys in Pandas!

Comment: Actually this is an official bug in pandas: link=https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8596

Answer (score 2):

Try something simple like this,

```
j = real.merge(fpm, how = 'right', on = ['region_id', 'month'])
```

As [pandas document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) mentions, "If joining columns on columns, the DataFrame indexes will be ignored. Otherwise if joining indexes on indexes or indexes on a column or columns, the index will be passed on".

Comment: As I said (comment above), the resulting frame does not have the information of fpm for which I don't have the gdp_region (in month 11, for example). Thus, I lose information. I want a table that is as complete as possible, although with `Nan` where my information is actually missing from the original database

Comment: @BFurtado try `how = 'outer'`, you'll get `NaN` values, which is what is your intended output.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in the example. But see that the results are incorrect. The Nans are good. But the same month and region_id has different values for fpm

Comment: @BFurtado I did it out of what I remember, if that is the case, you have to add `left_index=True, right_index=True` as noted in the quotes by pandas document. I'll update the answer.

Comment: please re-update the answer, since using `left_index=True`, `right_index=True` both, will create exactly OP's problem. I do not run into trouble using only 1 of them, but that will still create meaningless indices. :)

Comment: @Uvar true that! Updated!

Answer (score 2):

For a nearly symmetric solution in which the months are in the same order no matter which merge you execute, you can use (nearly) equivalent expressions:

```
j = fpm.merge(real, how = 'outer', on = ['region_id', 'month']).sort_values('month')

j2 = real.merge(fpm, how = 'outer', on = ['region_id', 'month']).sort_values('month')

j3 = pd.merge(real, fpm, how = 'outer', on = ['region_id', 'month']).sort_values('month')
```

Please notice that `left_index='off'` and the like is not how it is supported by pandas. It uses booleans, of which the default value is set to False, which is exactly the behaviour you'd like.

It returns for me:

```
   month         fpm  region_id    gdp_region
0     11  31065220.0    5300108           NaN
1     23  34764530.0    5300108           NaN
2     35  44809620.0    5300108  5.390220e+10
3     47  41485330.0    5300108  5.845612e+10
4     59  43249090.0    5300108  6.707650e+10
5     71  59087920.0    5300108  7.573268e+10
6     83  62187720.0    5300108  8.466141e+10
7     95  68813120.0    5300108  9.340400e+10
```

If that is not your result, then probably, there is an extra column called "fpm" in your dataframe called "real". I can, however, recreate your original problem by setting `left_index=True, right_index=True`, so I think your keyword definition using "off" made python interpret a boolean `True` instead of the required behaviour.

Now, using `left_index=True` will fill up missing indices because of data length difference with the last known index value:

```
j4 = pd.merge(fpm, real, how = 'outer', on = ['region_id', 'month'], left_index=True, right_index=False).sort_values('month')
           month         fpm  region_id    gdp_region
72402     11  31065220.0    5300108           NaN
72402     23  34764530.0    5300108           NaN
72397     35  44809620.0    5300108  5.390220e+10
72398     47  41485330.0    5300108  5.845612e+10
72399     59  43249090.0    5300108  6.707650e+10
72400     71  59087920.0    5300108  7.573268e+10
72401     83  62187720.0    5300108  8.466141e+10
72402     95  68813120.0    5300108  9.340400e+10
```

The other way around, the index is retained:

```
j5 = pd.merge(fpm, real, how = 'outer', on = ['region_id', 'month'], left_index=False, right_index=True).sort_values('month')
       month         fpm  region_id    gdp_region
94934     11  31065220.0    5300108           NaN
94935     23  34764530.0    5300108           NaN
94936     35  44809620.0    5300108  5.390220e+10
94937     47  41485330.0    5300108  5.845612e+10
94938     59  43249090.0    5300108  6.707650e+10
94939     71  59087920.0    5300108  7.573268e+10
94940     83  62187720.0    5300108  8.466141e+10
94941     95  68813120.0    5300108  9.340400e+10
```

And using both as `True` will just use all of the index-value combinations, and you end up with a lot of NaNs, or possibly if you have the actual data, fill with the values of that particular index-value combination:

```
j6 = pd.merge(fpm, real, how = 'outer', on = ['region_id', 'month'], left_index=True, right_index=True).sort_values('month')
       month         fpm  region_id    gdp_region
94934     11  31065220.0    5300108           NaN
94935     23  34764530.0    5300108           NaN
72397     35         NaN    5300108  5.390220e+10
94936     35  44809620.0    5300108           NaN
72398     47         NaN    5300108  5.845612e+10
94937     47  41485330.0    5300108           NaN
72399     59         NaN    5300108  6.707650e+10
94938     59  43249090.0    5300108           NaN
72400     71         NaN    5300108  7.573268e+10
94939     71  59087920.0    5300108           NaN
72401     83         NaN    5300108  8.466141e+10
94940     83  62187720.0    5300108           NaN
72402     95         NaN    5300108  9.340400e+10
94941     95  68813120.0    5300108           NaN
```